# Defining Multiple Types Instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, types

In my `Data` interface, I want `date` to be a `string` or a `[key: string]: sample_interface[]` but I am getting error on `data`:

`Property 'name' of type '{ [key: string]: Sample_interface[]; }' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string | number | Sample_interface[]'.`

How could I assign `date` to have a nested and non-nested type? See code below:

```
interface Sample_interface {
  sample_var1?: number;
  sample_var2?: number;

 // more variables
}

interface Data{
  data: {
    [key: string]: Sample_interface[];
  };
  [key: string]: number | string | Sample_interface[];

}
```

Comment: The code producing that error is not in your question, and the code you have posted [compiles fine](https://tsplay.dev/wOGrpw). Please add the code you have that uses these types and produces that error message.

Comment: @AlexWayne I updated my included with its corresponding error message

Answer (score 0):

Using type instead of interface, the solution would look something like this

```
type Result = Record<string, number | string | Sample_interface[]> & {
    data: {
        [key: string]: Sample_interface[]
    }
}
```